# dynamic template in elasticsearch affect performance?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have set mapping to most of the fields however I have few fields that I didn't specify a mapping however I've set a dynamic_templates therefore if given value for that field is a string it will be mapped as "keyword"

```
  "mappings": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
      {
        "strings": {
          "match_mapping_type": "string",
          "mapping": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

performance wise, would it be better to explicitly set mapping?

Comment: perf, migration, debug, indexing wise, it's better to have static mapping.

Answer (score 2):

Providing mapping initially is best as it will reduce indexing time.
If number of keys are high for which there will be dynamic mapping, it will hurt indexing performance as ES will first create mappings and then index.
But note this will happen once for one key.

Comment: even if I set dynamic mapping so that if given a string, it map to "keyword" ? Also would it have an affect in performance when querying?

Comment: The idea of dynamic mappings is that they run on fields that weren't already mapped, which means that if the field's type was already determined by a dynamic mapping, it won't run again. It doesn't matter what you map it to, the performance cost is a result of trying to find the field's type. As to when the performance cost occur at the first time, if it's a dynamic field, on write, if it's a runtime field, it's on read. https://www.elastic.co/blog/introducing-elasticsearch-runtime-fields
Hope that helps, a year and a half later haha